# Autogenerate CRUDs using sequelize and node js

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, crud, auto-generate

In *PHP* frameworks such as *CakePHP* it is possible to auto generate the entire CRUD functionality after creating the database. 
Is it possible to do this using sequelize and node js ? If so where can i find resources to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate models you can use [sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto) but you have to write code for controllers and views by yourself. I haven't found any npm package for generating boilerplate code like bake does in CakePHP.